# How to make a C# application act as a service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have developed a C# program, although when I try and create a service from it e.g.

```
sc create "servicetest" binPath= 
   "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test\test.exe" start= auto error= ignore
```

I get the following message:

```
[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create it as a service through the Visual Studio interface, which will provide you with the correct classes and methods you need to implement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to base your application on the Windows Service template available in Visual Studio (not available in the Standard Edition.) See here:

[How to: Create Windows Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way of implementing windows service using [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/). You can actually run a console application as windows service using topshelf. Advantage of it is easy to debug. As far As I know when you want to debug windows service, you have start the service in service console. Stop the service if you are compiling and service installed from build output directly. It is extra painful step.

If you are using topshelf, you can start the service like how you start windows forms application to debug. There are other benefits too. Please refer the web site.